# How to calculate closest location with ElasticSearch _geo_distance with multiple locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, elasticsearch, distance, tire

I successfully got ElasticSearch to return my results sorted on the distance from my given coordinates. Problem is that the distance that is being sorted on is the AVERAGE distance of the available locations from the coordinates, where I need to have the CLOSEST location.
[ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort/) says I can give an option "sort_mode" (`Note: the geo distance sorting supports sort_mode options: min, max and avg.`), but does not give an example with multiple locations.

I can see by the results.sort value that the average distance is returned, not the closest. What I eventually need is the distance to the closest location.

If anyone can help me to get this to work correctly, I would be very grateful! Thanks!

My relevant code:

```
  mapping do
    indexes :locations do
      indexes :geolocation, type: "geo_point"
    end
  end


  sort do
    by :_geo_distance, 
    :sort_mode => "min", #THIS DOES NOT WORK! FIELDS ARE ORDERED BY AVERAGE DISTANCE, NOT SHORTEST
    "locations.geolocation" => coordinates,
    :order => sort_direction,
    :unit => "km"
    end
  end
```

**UPDATE****

I have found that it isn't actually the average, but just the first distance Elasticsearch finds.
Also, I've tried to set just one field to type: "geo_point" with the x amount of coordinates in the hash, but I get the same results that way. If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong, please let me know, I would be very grateful for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ruby, but this seems like an elasticsearch problem more than a ruby problem.

If your field is actually indexed as `geo_point`, you should be able to sort by minimum distance.

The key for sort mode has changed in newer version of ES, so depending on the version of your ES, you might need to change the `sort_mode` to `mode`.

If changing `sort_mode` to `mode`doesn't work, could you try posting your types mapping as reported by elasticsearch, and also the version of ES that you are using?

Getting the type mapping is well documented here: [get mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-get-mapping/).